# Input file accept only PDF in typo3 Fluid

Tags: typo3, typo3-7.6.x, typo3-8.x, typo3-extensions

This is the method in Normal HTML to accept only PDF

```
<input type="file" name="myFile" accept="application/pdf" />
```

But How to use it with Typo3 Fluid? When I gave like this

```
<f:form.upload name="myFile" accept="application/pdf" />
```

It showed me an error as below

> **#1237823695: Argument "accept" was not registered.**

How can I do this in fluid?

(I'm using Typo3 7.6.21)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do this with `additionalAttributes`.

Here a link to the Fluid doc
https://fluidtypo3.org/viewhelpers/fluid/master/Form/UploadViewHelper.html

Complete ViewHelper Code looks like:

```
<f:form.upload additionalAttributes="{accept :'application/pdf'}" name="test2"/>
```